# Error in windows form calculator for 2 values only

Tags: c#, data-structures

Error is coming in num1+float.Parse(textBox1.text);
I am developing a calculator and whenever i click on number and then click on any operator the program stops saying input string was not in a correct format. I did not make any equal operator in calculator so when i will click on another value after clicking on operator it will show me the result in textox.

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox1.Focus();

        ans = num1 + float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = ans.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You don't know which programming language you're using?

Comment: its in C#. 
For textBox1.text it value is the first number that i will click on calculator and float is the data type of first number.

Answer (score 1):

You have cleared the text box.

Obviously you do not have anything in your textbox to add.

If you want increment, the textbox value, store the value in a temporary variable first.

Comment: thanks a lot it started working but now it is performing that operation on the same number that i entered first but i want to perform the operation on 2 numbers. Can you help me with a little code in that?

Comment: Are you going to enter the second number in same textbox

Comment: I guess... every alternate button click clears the fields to enter next value

Comment: I want that when i click the first button and then click on operator which just clear the texbox for 2nd value. i don't know how i can do that.

Comment: on operator click, before clearing, store the text box value in a global variable. Use that when you do button click